# Paypal notify_url doesnot return a value and nothing insert in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal

My problem is Notify_url does not insert any value in database. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong. I have following code pages available

I have three pages: 1) default.aspx 2) sendpayment.aspx 3) PAypal.aspx

In default.aspx,
I have two textbox. I get those two values in session and on submit I redirect a page to Sendpayment.aspx

In sendpayment.aspx, I have following code

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Sendpayment.aspx.vb" Inherits="Sendpayment" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="form1"
    name="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="naveed.mansuri@abc.com"/><!--Paypal or sandbox Merchant account -->

    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<%=Session("regemail")%>"/><!--Custom Field for payer email -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%=Session("totalShoppingAmt")%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.abc.com/paypal.aspx"/><!--this should be your domain web page where you going to receive all your transaction variables -->
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.abc.com/thankyou.html"/><!--this page will be your redirection page -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.abc.com"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>

</form>

<script type="text/jscript">
    document.form1.submit();
</script>
```

I have assign notify url at http://www.abc.com/paypal.aspx

In Paypal.aspx,

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Paypal.aspx.vb" Inherits="Paypal" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html
```

and vb page of this is:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net


Partial Public Class paypal
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Post back to either sandbox or live
    Dim strSandbox As String = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
    ' string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(strSandbox), HttpWebRequest)

    'Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim param As Byte() = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
    Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param)
    strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate"
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

    'for proxy
    'WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
    'req.Proxy = proxy;

    'Send the request to PayPal and get the response

    Dim txnid As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("txn_id"))
    Dim receiv_email As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("receiver_email"))
    Dim business As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("business"))
    Dim payer_email As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("payer_email"))
    Dim tnx_type As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("txn_Type"))
    Dim payment_type As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("payment_type"))
    Dim payment_stat As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("payment_status"))
    Dim regemail As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form("custom"))
    ' this is where i get my member's email adress
    Dim constr As String = "data source=activehost.com;initial catalog=demo;password=R12ComSQ;persist security info=True;user id=demo_sa"
    Dim insertsql As String = "INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION_PAYPAL_TRANSACTION (txn_id,receiver_email,business,payer_email,tnx_type,payment_status,LocalDate,payment_type,regemail) values('" & txnid & "','" & receiv_email & "','" & business & "','" & payer_email & "','" & tnx_type & "','" & payment_stat & "','" & DateTime.Now.ToString() & "','" & payment_type & "','" & regemail & "')"
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(constr)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand(insertsql, myConnection)

        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Using

    ' for testing purposes i did not create any ipn status actions as i wanted to record every paypal status.
    'If strResponse = "VERIFIED" Then
    '    'UPDATE YOUR DATABASE



    '    'check the payment_status is Completed
    '    'check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    '    'check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    '    'check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    '    'process payment


    '    'UPDATE YOUR DATABASE


    'ElseIf strResponse = "INVALID" Then
    '    'UPDATE YOUR DATABASE
    'Else
    'End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the IPN History in your PayPal to see if anything is getting sent or not.  You may find that it's showing it's sending data but getting a bad response back.

If it shows it's sending data but getting anything other than a 200 response then something is wrong with the script that needs to be fixed.  You can check your web server logs for help with that, or what I like to do is build an HTML form with the action set to my IPN script and a bunch of hidden fields that match what I expect to get from an IPN.  Then I submit that in a browser and actually see the result on screen which can help trouble problems.

Once it's working that way you know you're good.  Just remember the data isn't coming from PayPal when you do that, so it won't verify successfully.  You'll need to make sure your code logic can handle that.

If your IPN History doesn't show anything is getting sent then I would question whether you're looking at the correct sandbox account.  It's easy to get them confused and be looking at the wrong one.

Comment: YEs as you say IPN History is showing sent for every transaction. But I did not get anything. 

and I am using sandbox account from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

Am I using correct sandbox account? If not which should I use?